# Expand and collapse button javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on expanding and collapsing a button. I have two images here and the focus should stay on the element. If clicked once it should `collapse` and another click should `expand`. I tried focussing the element but  `.focus()` isn't working.

**HTML**:

```
<td  aria-expanded="false" name="td_tohide2" id="td_tohide2" style="padding:0px;" class="sectiontd" nowrap="true" >
  <img  role="button" aria-labelledby="hide_show" id="generalinfo_caretup" src="images/arrow_up_ps_oc.png" onkeypress="sh_keypress('td_tohide2','td_toshow2','generaltable',event)" onclick="sh('td_tohide2','td_toshow2','generaltable')" tabindex="0" />
</td>

<td aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="hide_show_" name="td_toshow2" id="td_toshow2" style="padding:0px;display:none" class="sectiontd" nowrap="true">
  <img role="button" id="generalinfo_caretdown" src="images/arrow_down_ps_oc.png" onkeypress="sh_keypress('td_toshow2','td_tohide2','generaltable',event)" onclick="sh('td_toshow2','td_tohide2','generaltable')" tabindex="0" />
</td>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function sh_keypress(a,b,c,event){
  if( event.keyCode==13 || event.keyCode==32 || event.which==13 || event.which==32) {  
    if(document.getElementById(c).style.display=="none")
      document.getElementById(c).style.display = "";
    else
      document.getElementById(c).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById(a).style.display="none"; //arrow images
      document.getElementById(b).style.display=""; //arrow images
      setTimeout("document.getElementById(b).focus()",1000);
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();  
    }   
  }
function sh(a,b,c)
  {

if(document.getElementById(c).style.display=="none")
  document.getElementById(c).style.display = "";
else
  document.getElementById(c).style.display = "none";


document.getElementById(a).style.display="none"; //arrow images
document.getElementById(b).style.display=""; //arrow images
}
```

Can anyone give idea how can i focus the element.

Comment: Can you share a more complete code sample? It appears you've only shared part of your code.

Comment: i've shared both the html and the js function

Comment: you say focus, Focus is like you do. but don't provide a string to setTimeout but provide a  real function. convert `"..."` to `function(){...}`

Answer (score 1):

What is `sh`? You haven't provided a function with that name. Assuming the function was provided and follows the same pattern, you will need to ensure the value of `b` is passed into `setTimeout`.

The value of `b` in your current `setTimeout` is most likely undefined. This is because `setTimeout` is executed in the global context by default. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
function sh_keypress(a,b,c,event) {
    if(event.keyCode==13 || event.keyCode==32 || event.which==13 || event.which==32) {  
        if(document.getElementById(c).style.display === 'none') {
            document.getElementById(c).style.display = "";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(c).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(a).style.display="none"; //arrow images
            document.getElementById(b).style.display=""; //arrow images
            // Use a function below to provide the value of `b` from `sh_keypress` scope
            setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(b).focus()},1000);
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @anuu: Please provide a complete example. The `sh` function does not exist in your code so I can't determine where the issue occurs.

Comment: I've put the sh function also now.. can u please look into it..the focus() isnt working